# count number of words in a line in cshell

Tags: linux, shell

I need to count the number of words in a line, in cshell. The words are separated by a space or numerous spaces. For example,

```
fish duck     cheese            bacon
```

would return 4. Is there a simple command for that that I'm missing?

Comment: wc http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc

Comment: wc works for files, I'm looking for a function that will work on a string in the shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $ echo "fish duck     cheese            bacon" | wc -w
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that. Thanks.